# Monad terminology/reference request

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, monads

I am looking at a category $C$ equipped with an exponential, and a monad $T : C  \to C$ equipped with a natural transformation $\nu : F \to G$ from the bifunctor $F : (X, Y) \mapsto T(Y^X)$ to the bifunctor $G : (X, Y) \mapsto T(Y)^X$. Original question: Does anyone know if such monads have been studied? Is there a name for such a monad?

I should say more about $T$ and $\nu$. My $T$ is strong with respect to the product $\times$ used to define the evaluation morphism $\varepsilon_{X,Y} : X \times Y^X \to Y$. Writing $\sigma_{X,Y} : X \times TY \to T(X \times Y)$ for the strength natural transformation, I now see that my $\nu_{X,Y} : T(Y^X) \to T(Y)^X$ is adjoint to the composite:

$$
X \times T(Y^X) \stackrel{\sigma_{X,Y^X}}{\longrightarrow} T(X \times Y^X)
   \stackrel{T(\varepsilon_{X, Y})}{\longrightarrow} TY
$$

So the answer to the original question for that particular $\nu$ is that its existence is just a by-product of $T$ being strong. I suppose the question remains whether there is any interest in abstracting over $\nu$. The comment by Maciej Piróg below suggests that the existence of a $\nu$ satisfying suitable naturality conditions might be equivalent to the strength of $T$.

Comment: Do you have any conditions on the natural transformation $\nu$, for example about how it interacts with $\eta$ or $\mu$?

Comment: If, as suggested by Arnaud, the natural transformation is appropriately compatible with $\mu$ and $\eta$, isn't it an alternative definition of a strong monad? We obtain $\nu = \Phi(T\mathsf{apply} \cdot \mathsf{st})$ (where $\Phi$ is appropriate adjunct of the product-exponential adjunction) and $\mathsf{st} = \mathsf{apply} \cdot (\nu \times \mathsf{id}) \cdot (T(\theta) \times \mathsf{id})$ (where $\theta$ is unit of the product-exponential adjunction). I didn't check if appropriate diagrams commute, but the types seem fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comments: I have since realised that the $\nu$ that I had constructed concretely exists by a general construction when the monad is strong w.r.t. the product used in the definition of the exponential (which is the case in the category I am looking at).

Comment: @MaciejPiróg: I've updated my question: if you'd like to write your comment up as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.